# Talend - how to configure tFileInputDelimited do not throw error when file not found

Tags: talend

Good day,

I am using `tFileInputDelimited` in `Talend Data Studio` to read a txt file and get some value inside.

The input file name is something like follow, it contain day in the file name:
`checksum_150123.txt`

This file will create in last few steps before the job end and the file not found.

Thus, every day the job first run, there is no file exist, and then `tFileInputDelimited` will throw error on file not found.

```
C:\LandingZone\jx\checksum_180123.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
[ERROR] 14:13:35 my_track.my_precheck_registration_0_1.DL_PRECHECK_REGISTRATION- CollectCheckSum_1_tFileInputDelimited_1 - C:\LandingZone\jx\checksum_180123.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I have a requirement to not showing this, may I know how can I configure this?

Comment: Get a file list from the folder and see if it exists first, simple.

Answer (score 2):

for that I recommend you to use the tFileExist component and then use the tFileExist variable Exist (((Boolean)globalMap.get("tFileExist_1_EXISTS")) for example) in a run if trigger[image]

Hope this answers your question